# Firewall blocks Email Recommendations when using email address in image link

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, einstein-recommendations

I have implemented email recommendations as usual, so email address is used for getting image link like in there

```
https://<MID>.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/5dc59c2c08401e003069478e/i/1/%%emailaddr%%
```

But some subscribers report that images are not visible in email clients. When I made a test so image is something other than email address (I chose subscriber key)

```
https://MID.recs.igodigital.com/rr/v2/5dc59c2c08401e003069478e/i/1/%%_subscriberkey%%
```

images started to appear they said.

Has anybody encountered such behaviour? I was unable to reproduce the error but I believe that it was caused by firewalls since urls contain email address which is not safe. Maybe you met something like this and have any good practice for how to correctly use uniqueid rather email address?

Comment: Ensure whatever value you use at the end of the url is the same value you are using in the setuserinfo in the collect code

Comment: Hi, it seems that the problem is not due to firewall but weird behaviour for non IGO_Profile subscribers only which is not yet recognized by setuserinfo. I used to see results for such subscribers in another business units. Anyone experienced such problem? I use custom HTML for displaying email recommendations, not Einstein Content since it produces HTML containing %%emailaddr%%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't encountered this problem - however regarding "good practice" you have made the right decision to use a value that is not an email address for the recommendations.
The IGO identifies a user by whatever value you give it during the "[Set User Info](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_set_user_info.htm&type=5)" call in the [Collect Tracking Code](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ctc_install_collect_code.htm&type=5) configuration.

Note that "SubscriberKey" can sometimes render as an EmailAddress if you did not provide a SubscriberKey when a subscriber was added to the database. Google Analytics also has a very strict policy about Personally Identifiable Information (eg, EmailAddresses) being captured in their platform.

To remove this risk, try using **_SubscriberID**.
It's a 1:1 match with SubscriberKey in the [_Subscribers data view](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_subscribers.htm&type=5), and will ensure you never accidentally send PII to your website.

SubscriberID is also the default value sent by SFMC in the "sfmc_id" parameter in the [GA360 Audience Integration in Journey Builder](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_gai_audience_activation.htm&type=5). It's also the default value for the "sfmc_sub" parameter used in [Conversion Tracking](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_conversion_landingpg.htm&type=5). This means less development for you in the future.

Making this change will invalidate any data you've captured for predictions to date; however we are very happy with our decision to change.

Comment: Hi Cameron. Thanks for the tips. SubscriberID sounds good since 100% sure I will go GA360 in next phase. My only concern is that lead generation is within Sales Cloud and I cannot easily get SubscriberID from Marketing Cloud on Sales Cloud Lead creation (it's simple Apex REST API). Now I am able to set user info as Lead ID. Will consider pros and cons internally.

Comment: There are ways to get subscriber details (such as email or SubscriberKey) from SFMC using SubscriberID. You could use the ListSubscribers SOAP API, or you could make your own DE that matches the SubscriberIDs in your recommendations, and use the DE lookup REST API (undocumented, search for it on StackExchange).

Comment: Cameron, I see lots of benefits of using SubscriberID now. Do you think that for simplicity and "double opt in" manner would it be good to track users in "set user info" only by sending this event when subscriber clicks on conversion tracking link? This could result in higher opens in another device (especially mobile phone). And don't know if the IGO cookie is same for Gmail in-app browser and mobile browser. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hey Mariusz, we are firing the “set user info” when a valid SFMC_ID parameter is found in the URL. We’re unsure how the ITP 2.3 update affects IGO cookies; but firing it more often than needed shouldn’t cause any damage. We do conversions tracking on all links to ensure we are sending SubscriberIDs to our website as often as possible. You can’t retarget what you’re not tracking!